# How to properly change the font size from MUI TextField Label

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, label

I would like to be able to change the label fontSize from the material ui TextField component. I've come up with the InputLabelProps which works great, but as you can see in the picture bellow the label is too squeezy when focused

[image]

Here is my implementation of the TextField

```
<TextField {...params} InputLabelProps={{
    style : {color: '#518eb9', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 1000}
}} label="Hovedkategori" />
```

I've found out that the label displayed when focused actually comes from another tag:

```
<legend class="css-1ftyaf0"><span>Hovedkategori</span></legend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want resolve this problem you should add into your TextField component an css that modify MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline class.
With sx you can modify this class, and set the same font-size for fix your problem.

*"&.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { fontSize: "28px" }*

```
<TextField
    InputLabelProps={{
      sx: {
        color: "#518eb9",
        fontSize: "28px",
        fontWeight: 1000,
        "&.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { fontSize: "28px" }
      }
    }}
    label="Hovedkategori"
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mui `Box` component and set `fontSize` and `fontWeight`

```
const LabelValue = (label) => {
    return (
        <Box color="#518eb9" fontSize={18} fontWeight={1000}>
            {label}
        </Box>
    )
}

 <TextField label={LabelValue("Hovedkategori")} />
```

Comment: +1. This allows more customization to the label with this method, like adding a border or color. To stay consistent, set `TextField`'s  `InputLabelProps={{shrink: true}}` to force the label always show on top instead of placeholder when the value is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, try to use Mui Theme provider to create a override style theme. There are many small divs there that can get in your way, hide them or move them.
[MUI themes](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/)

Comment: Hey, @ivanpetrijevci, could you share your code with me?
I am kind of new in Material UI

Comment: Hi, @lucasbbs.dk I've switched from mui textfield to mui select, the logic behind it is same, I've provided you the link of my theme so you can understand it better [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gehjunc8/)